# Webform with Content Access module not allowing access for the authenticated user role

Tags: 7, webforms, users

I've run in to an interesting problem that I've not been able to solve yet.

I've got a webform that is restricted to only be able to be accessed by users with a certain role, called "member".

But upon testing I see that users with this 'member' role are not allowed to access the webform unless I have the content access per node allow for *anonymous* users to access it as well. When I allow "anonymous" access to the webform,  I can actually get it to come up for the member role.

When a logged in "member" tries to access the webform I'm getting the "accessed denied" page.

On the actual form itself under *webform > Form*  settings I've got the "submission access" set to allow my "member" role, but not anonymous users.

I've looked at the general user permissions too, and everything seems to be in place:

- checked: view published content
- checked: Access own webform results
- checked: access own webform submissions

I've enabled access control on the webform content type itself, and allowed anonymous as well as authenticated (and "member") access to all webforms generally.

I'm using the [Content Access](https://drupal.org/project/content_access) module to attempt to restrict access to this particular node/form to authenticated "members". Both authenticated and member roles are checked so as to allow access.

That role is assigned upon a user completing their checkout, and I've double-checked to make sure it's appropriately assigned and it's in place. This part works fine.

I cannot have this webform open for anonymous users.

Any ideas as to what's keeping this node from being able to be accessed?

Comment: You write: "When I allow 'anonymous' access to the webform, I can actually get it to come up for the member role." and then: "When a logged in 'member' tries to access the webform I'm getting the 'accessed denied' page."  So which one is it - does the form "come up" or does it show "access denied"? I don't understand your question. I can guess it is: "How can I grant the 'Member' role access to my webform without also allowing access for the 'Anonymous' role?", but it is only a guess.  Please edit your question to make sure it states clearly: 1) What you want, and 2) what is currently wrong.

Comment: I think it could possibly be a bug with the Content Access module. I switched to Nodeaccess and my problem was resolved.

Comment: and just to clarify for those who may encounter this in the future, the issue was granting access to the "member" role while excluding the "anonymous" role. They were behaving in the same way. They were either both allowed to view the content, or they were both excluded, despite what permissions were set.